# Why does the symbol '{' remain when f"\{10}" is evaluated in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, f-string

The `f-string` is one of the new features in Python 3.6.

But when I try this:

```
>>> f"\{10}"
'\\{10'
```

I can't figure out why the left curly brace `'{'` remains in the result. I supposed that the result should be same with the `str.format`:

```
>>> "\{}".format(10)
'\\10'
```

In [PEP-0498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) it doesn't answer this explicitly. So what causes that the left curly brace `'{'` to remain in the result and what causes this difference between `f-string` and `str.format()`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug. An approach that currently works is to use the Unicode literal `\u005c` for `\` instead:

```
>>> f'\u005c{10}'
'\\10'
```

or, with a similar effect, using a raw `f`-string:

```
>>> rf'\{10}'
'\\10'
```

By using `'\'` it seems that the two weird things happen at the same time:

- The next character (`'{'` here) was escaped, leaving it in the resulting string.
- The formatted string is also *evaluated*, which is odd and not expected

Case in point:

```
>>> f'\{2+3}'
'\\{5'
>>> a = 20
>>> f'\{a+30}'
'\\{50'
```

<strike>Either way, I'll be filling out a bug report soon (since I see you haven't already) and update when I get a reply.</strike>

Update: Created *[Issue 29104 -- Left bracket remains in format string result when '\' preceeds it](http://bugs.python.org/issue29104)*, if you're interested take a look at the conversation there.

Update 2: Issue resolved with [PR 490](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/490).